# Flutter Riverpod FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I trying to use riverpod to do a search but without success, I create one FutureProvider and when I create my Widget I run watch a FutureProvider with a default value, so then I need to click in a button and execute the search again with another value. the logic work byt why the CircularProgressIndicator dont show when I click a button?

tks

my service

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:i_condominio/models/Condominio.dart';

final condominioPRovider = Provider((ref) => CondominioService());

final condFuture =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<List<Condominio>, String>((ref, arg) {
  final serviceProvider = ref.watch(condominioPRovider);
  return serviceProvider.findByCepFuture(arg);
});

class CondominioService {
  Future<List<Condominio>> findByCepFuture(String cepProcura) async {
    List<Condominio> listCondominio = [
      Condominio(
          nome: 'Porto panorama',
          cep: Cep(
              cep: "11075-350",
              logradouro: "Rua Monsenhor Paula Rodrigues",
              complemento: "",
              bairro: "Vila Belmiro",
              localidade: "Santos",
              uf: "SP",
              ibge: "3548500"),
          numero: "129"),
      Condominio(
          nome: 'Central Park',
          cep: Cep(
              cep: "11075-350",
              logradouro: "Rua Monsenhor Paula Rodrigues",
              complemento: "",
              bairro: "Vila Belmiro",
              localidade: "Santos",
              uf: "SP",
              ibge: "3548500"),
          numero: "126"),
      Condominio(
          nome: 'Sao Vicente park',
          cep: Cep(
              cep: "11380-120",
              logradouro: "Rua Monsenhor Paula Rodrigues",
              complemento: "",
              bairro: "Vila Belmiro",
              localidade: "Santos",
              uf: "SP",
              ibge: "3548500"),
          numero: "130")
    ];
    print('buscando $cepProcura');
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    final retorno = listCondominio
        .where((element) => element.cep.cep == cepProcura)
        .toList();
    print('acabou ${retorno.length}');
    return Future.value(retorno);
  }
}
```

and my widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:i_condominio/models/Condominio.dart';
import 'package:i_condominio/services/CondominioService.dart';
import 'package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart';

class SelecionarCondominioPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SelecionarCondominioPage({super.key});
  selecionarCondoninio(Condominio e) {
    print('condominio Selecionado ${e.nome}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final cf = ref.watch(condFuture('11380-120'));

    var maskFormatter = MaskTextInputFormatter(
        mask: '#####-###',
        filter: {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')},
        type: MaskAutoCompletionType.lazy);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Novo usuario'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'CEP',
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              "Condominios encontrados",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => ref.watch(condFuture('11075-350')),
            child: const Text('Buscar 11075-350'),
          ),
          cf.when(
              data: (data) => Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        ...data.map((e) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(e.nome),
                            subtitle: Text(e.enderecoCompleto),
                            onTap: () => showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: ((ctx) => AlertDialog(
                                        title: const Text(
                                            'Condominio selecionado'),
                                        content: Text(
                                            'Confirma o condominio ${e.nome}'),
                                        actions: [
                                          const TextButton(
                                              onPressed: null,
                                              child: Text("OK")),
                                          TextButton(
                                              onPressed: () =>
                                                  Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                              child: const Text("CANCELAR")),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                )))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
              error: (error, n) => Text(error.toString()),
              loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a FutureBuilder if you have a FutureProvider?  Just use .when on the AsyncValue, and select amongst your three states there.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz sorry. I  wrote wrong, :D I correct

Comment: How do you expect the button to change what you are watching, which is a constant `ref.watch(condFuture('11380-120'))`.  If you want the value to change, it'll need too update that parameter.  Put that into a state variable and have your control callback update state and call setStatee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it is better to use the `StateNotifierProvider`, as indicated in the documentation

> FutureProvider does not offer a way of directly modifying the
> computation after a user interaction. It is designed to solve simple
> use-cases. For more advanced scenarios, consider using
> StateNotifierProvider.

Provider

```dart
final condominioNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CondominioNotifier,
    AsyncValue<List<Condominio>>>((ref) {
  final service = ref.watch(condominioPRovider);

  return CondominioNotifier(service);
});


class CondominioNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<Condominio>>> {
  CondominioNotifier(this.service) : super(const AsyncValue.loading()) {
    load('11380-120');
  }

  final CondominioService service;

  Future<void> load(String name) async {
    state = AsyncValue.loading();

    try {
      final data = await service.findByCepFuture(name);
      state = AsyncValue.data(data);
    }  on Exception catch(e) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, StackTrace.current);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Widget

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final cf = ref.watch(condominioNotifierProvider);
    ...
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => ref.read(condominioNotifierProvider.notifier).load('11075-350'),
      child: const Text('Buscar 11075-350'),
    ),
    ...
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button event to trigger a provider. The only difference is you don't use an async provider but instead use a notifier provider. This way you can call the provider only when you need it to run such as when a button is pressed.

Here's a snippet using Riverpod annotation while making a Firebase query.

#### Create the service

Create the service that will call all Firebase commands:

```dart
class MyService {

  ...

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> myAsyncMethod() async {
    try {
      var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      var ref = db.collection('MY-COLLECTION').doc('MY-DOC-ID');
      var snap = await ref.get();

      if(!snap.exists) return null;
      return snap.data();
    } catch (err, _) {
      print(err);
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

#### Create the provider that uses the service

Once you have the service set up use the provider to set things up so you can monitor its loading state:

```dart
@riverpod
class MyNotifier extends _$MyNotifier {

  // We don't care about build() so just return an empty map
  @override
  FutureOr<Map<String, dynamic>> build() => {};

  // This is what matters to us
  Future<void> foo() async {
    // Set state as loading
    state = const AsyncLoading<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    // Will get the value or throw an error courtesy of `AsyncValue.guard()`
    state = await AsyncValue.guard<Map<String, dynamic>>(() => MyService.myAsyncMethod());
  }
}
```

#### Trigger it with a button

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // We watch it but it doesn't do much because we know it's an empty map
  // We still need this so we can monitor its progress
  final asyncFoo = ref.watch(myNotifierProvider);


  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        

        // Show different states of the button
        asyncFoo.maybeWhen(
          // This is why we set state to `AsyncLoading()`
          loading: () => ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: Text("Pls wait, I'm working..."),
          ),
          orElse: () => ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => ref.read(myNotifierProvider.notifier).foo(),
            child: Text('Click me'),
          ),
        ),

        
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

#### Optional: Returning a value

Should `MyService.foo()` return a value and you need access to that value then all you have to do is create a listener to check if there is a value.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final asyncFoo = ref.watch(myNotifierProvider);

  // Listener that's waiting for a value
  ref.listen(myNotifierProvider, (prev, next) {
    // Check that it's not in the loading state and has a value
    if (!next.isLoading && next.hasValue) {
      // Here fooData has the value you need
      final fooData = next.value;
    }
  });

}
```

If you don't check for `next.isLoading` (which I initially didn't do) you'll end up with 2 values since the loading state will always precede the actual data. Basically, the first value is due to `AsyncLoading()` (which we don't want) and the other one is due to `AsyncValue.data()` (which we want).